# OutOfMemoryException when using Report.Render() method despite plentiful memory available

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

A client of our company is encountering a periodic OutOfMemoryException when the Report.Render() method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reporting.webforms.report.render) is invoked.  This occurs despite all indications showing that the operating system has plentiful memory available to it at the point of failure.  In this case, the report is fed an RDLC file that has an embedded image.  The size of the RDLC file 321KB.

We added some memory diagnostics to the process in question:

- Immediately prior to the Render() method call, the worker process shows having a memory footprint of approximately 412MB, though naturally this amount varies.  It never has been seen higher than 600MB.  (This was determined using **GC.GetTotalMemory(false)**.)
- Immediately prior to the Render() method call, the operating system reports the following memory availability on the system (which was determined using the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex)):

```
Memory in use....................: 28%
Total physical memory............: 8191MB
Available physical memory........: 5880MB
Total paging file................: 28671MB
Available paging file............: 26318MB
Total virtual memory.............: 4095MB
Available virtual memory.........: 4007MB
Available extended virtual memory: 0MB
```

Here is a portion of the stack trace; note that the exact point of failure sometimes varies, as does the exact exception that is reported.  But by far the most common exception is OutOfMemoryException:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.SharedRenderer.GetImage(RPLReport rplReport, Byte[]& imageData, Int64 imageDataOffset, GDIImageProps& gdiImageProps)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.GetImage(String imageName, Byte[] imageData, Int64 imageDataOffset, GDIImageProps gdiImageProps)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.DrawImage(RectangleF position, RPLImage image, RPLImageProps instanceProperties, RPLImagePropsDef definitionProperties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessImage(RPLMeasurement measurement, RectangleF position)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessReportItem(RPLMeasurement measurement, RectangleF bounds, Boolean renderBorders, Boolean hasTablixCellParent)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessNonTablixContainerReportItems(RPLContainer container, RectangleF bounds)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessReportItem(RPLMeasurement measurement, RectangleF bounds, Boolean renderBorders, Boolean hasTablixCellParent)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessPage(RPLReport rplReport, Int32 pageNumber, FontCache sharedFontCache, List`1 paragraphsItemizedData)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, Hashtable renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RendererBase.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition, Boolean& dataCached)
```

This app pool that runs this web app is configured with Private Memory Limit, Request Limit, and Virtual Memory Limit values all set to 0 (no limit).

Within our code, after the Render() method calls, we also invoke the following to attempt to release the memory that was grabbed by the report generation:

```
report.DataSources.Clear();
report.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
report.Dispose();
```

I would welcome any thoughts or suggestions on this issue.

Comment: can you do a !dumpheap.

Comment: This can occurs when your report is too big. Playing with memory management is almost useless. What is your datasource? Probably you have too many data in it, and you need to optimize it...
I currently have the same problem in an ActiveReport, where a filter return way too many data to process...

Comment: Is it a 32bit or a 64bit process?

Comment: @terrencep: That was going to be one of my next avenues of research, yes.  Haven't gone there just yet.

Comment: @Bestter: We've only been looking at the data from a memory footprint standpoint, but haven't actually dug into the data itself.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Idov: 32-bit. We'd love to switch it over to 64-bit, but our web app suffers significant performance issues when we do.  (That's a separate issue which is out of scope for this.)

Comment: @kfelvoirny: ok, 32bit processes are limited to about 1.3GB (maybe a little more) - no matter how much RAM your machine has. It may have momentarily reached this memory usage and crashed. It is possible that whatever tool you used to track the memory missed it (did not sample the ram status in the correct moment).

Comment: @Idov: I'd like to think that we're not hitting the 32-bit memory limit.  We're sampling it throughout our method: upon entry, prior to and following the SetParameters call, prior to and following the Render call, and at a few other places, as well.  In all instances, it's showing comparable memory stats, all of which are well under the 32-bit thresholds.

Comment: @kfelvoirny: You can easily check it by compiling your process to 64bit and running it (without considering your performance issues). If it is the case, you will see the x64 process' memory rise over 1.3G (x64 processes don't memory usage limitations).